# height percentage problem for body tag - unresolved through searches

Tags: css, html, height

I have read a vast amount of posts on the subject of css heights filling the viewport and have failed to find a working answer. So I'm reluctantly starting yet another thread about this in the hope of finding the missing part of the jigsaw I have probably been staring at without seeing it.

My DOCTYPE is xhtml transitional and I'm currently testing on IE6, FF6 and Safari 5 with the same problem.

I have a container `div` that also displays an image driven border within a table and I want this to fill the browser window, no bigger, no smaller but adaptable to each browser (minimum heights will be set to ensure all content is contained to account for older resolutions).

I have set the html and body styles as follows:-

```
html {
    height:auto !important;
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    border: solid;
    border-color: black;
    overflow: hidden;
}

body {
    height: 100%;
    height:auto !important;
    min-height: 100%;
    border: solid;
    border-color: black;
}
```

As you can see I have added a border to each of the elements so that I can actually see the size of each when I view the page. The html element fills the window fine, but the body element doesn't. It just shows a short box along the top of the window.

Can anyone offer a suggestion as to what may be causing the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is all you need for the css:

```
html,body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/tw16/gyAKJ/

Comment: @rikudo: I did a brief test with my fiddle and there didn't seem to be any issues.

Comment: Thanks for this. I had to do a few tweaks to get it sorted but I think it was the padding and margin bit that made it work, though I haven't tested it on IE7 yet but the browsers I mentioned in the question are generally okay. Although for some reason FF6 on mac looks different to FF6 on PC in that the container div is longer, but nothing's perfect in this game so no worries.